# Hello i am trying to integrate azure ad b2c authentication in my nextjs app, receiving an error code challenge must be present

Tags: reactjs, next.js, azure-active-directory, next-auth, azure-ad-b2c

The thing is i have integrated azure ad b2c using next auth package. It throws code challenge error that i am attaching here.

[image: Error Screenshot]

After going through some more documentation for SPA we need to add a code challenge and code challenge method into query parameters which i did but after that when i log in it throws callBack error not sure what i have done wrong here as i have the route defined and a page created for the callback url i provided.

[image: Callback error]

i have gone through the documentation and sample project provided by next auth and still receiving this error.

Update: you have to pass checks parameter to azureB2cProvider in next auth for it to work

```
AzureADB2CProvider({
  tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME,
  clientId: process?.env?.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_ID || "",
  clientSecret: process?.env?.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET || "",
  primaryUserFlow: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW,

  authorization: {
    params: {
      scope: `offline_access openid`,
    },
  },
  checks: ["pkce"],
}),
```

After this fix the first error went away but i faced a new error
[image: Client secret error]

I am pretty sure i am missing a parameter or 2 in Next Auth AzureB2cProvider which is really depressing like, why next auth has this really bad in-complete documentation with no params insights?

Comment: Does this help https://benjaminwfox.com/blog/tech/how-to-configure-azure-b2c-with-nextjs?

Comment: actually this is for v3 still i got past the first problem of code challenge by placing 

    checks:["pkce"]
inside the AzureADB2CProvider i am recieving a new error after this which is 
OAuthCallbackError : Public clients should not send a client_secret when redeeming a publicly acquired grant.
not sure should i update the question or still look for ways to fix it own my own

Comment: Check whether [Allow public client flows](https://i.imgur.com/9mVlpKE.png) is enabled. If yes the disable it and pass the client_secret

Comment: it is disabled by default.

Comment: Try not passing the ClientSecret value. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#2-get-an-access-token).

Comment: when i pass the client secret it throws the above error and when i don't it says client_secret_basic client authentication method requires a client_secret

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249697/discussion-between-rukmini-and-momin-naveed).

Answer (score 4):

so basically i was missing some parameters when setting up azure ad b2c with next auth.

```
checks:["pkce"]
client: {
token_endpoint_auth_method: 'none'
},
```

these 2 parameter were necessary for next auth to work with azure b2c, secondly i was missing some claims in my user flow which were needed like email addresses and User Object id. The documentation for next auth needs to improve in my humble opinion nevertheless posting this answer for other people future refrence. Thanks!
Special thanks to @Rukmini for helping me out